# Adding elements into queue from a list Python

Tags: python, list, deque

Is there anyway to add the elements of a list into a deque list, then use the queue and then pop the elements in it? Say I have the list:

```
a = [4,-1,4,1,1]
```

And I want to add it in order. First add the -1 to the queue then run it through something else pop the -1, then add the 1s run it then pop the elements in it, then the 4s run the queue then pop the elements in it.

Comment: `from collections import deque;
 b = deque(a)`

Answer (score 1):

It is still unclear what exactly you are trying to do. You should include more code from what you have tried to implement.

You can reverse sort your `list` and add that incrementally to your `deque`.

```
from collections import deque
a = [4, -1, 4, 1, 1]

sorted_a = sorted(a, reverse=True)

a_deque = deque()
a_deque.append(sorted_a.pop())
```

If you want to use the `deque` in the way you described above this may be what you are looking for:

```
# Reverse sorts a list so that calling pop()
# pop's elements "in order".
a_sorted_list = sorted(a, reverse=True)
a_reverse_sorted_deque = deque(a_sorted_list)

a_reverse_sorted_deque.pop()

# A regularly sorted list would require you to
# popleft
a_sorted_deque = deque(sorted(a))
a_sorted_deque.popleft()
```